# Resizing Tables in a Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

I'm trying to resize a table in a modern site and I can't seem to 'grab' the right border to resize it.

Any hints/tips/tricks?

***I'm also experiencing this for tables within a text box. When hovering over the line, SOMETIMES the icon appears and sometimes it does not. I cannot figure out a pattern to this.

Comment: Which table do you mean? Is it in web part or somewhere else? Could you please provide some screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about table in a "Text" web part, you have to hover on the right side of column border until you see the below icon, then select the border & drag it to left/right to resize the column width:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Add text, tables, and images to your page with the Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)